# Intersection of line with circle as function of distance from circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, intersection-theory

I'm trying to figure out if there is an analytical expression for this problem, or if it's going to be a transcendental equation no matter what:

Imagine that you have a circle of radius R centered at the origin (see figure below). There is a point directly above the circle at a distance D from the origin.  As a function of D, is it possible to predict where a line from the point will intersect the circle?

[image: Figure 1 - Showing the basic setup, and that I'm trying to determine X]

In other words, knowing R and D, can I find X?  (If I can find X, I can find Y, obviously).

I ran some numerical calculations, and you can see that as D gets large, X converges to R, which is exactly what you'd expect.  And, as D approaches R (in this case I picked R = 1), X goes to zero.

[image: Figure 2 - Showing how X/R goes to 1 as D goes to very large numbers]

I tried to fit this data with a function, and the best I can come up with with is:

x/R = ArcTan[a*D^2 + b*D + c]

It's an ugly function, but it works.  Any help solving this analytically is appreciated!

Comment: A line from the point above the circle, intersects when $SS_1 =0$. Let equation of circle be $ x^2+y^2=R^2$.  $xx_1+yy_1 = 0$ the point on line satisfies the equation of circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use $$R^2=D\sqrt{R^2-x^2},$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{R}{D}\sqrt{D^2-R^2}.$$
Indeed, let $A$ be a exterior point, $B$ be a touching point, $O$ be a center of the circle and $BC$ be a perpendicular to $AO$.

Thus, $\Delta ABO\sim\Delta BCO,$ which gives
$$\frac{AO}{BO}=\frac{BO}{CO}$$ or
$$BO^2=AO\cdot CO.$$

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct.  For my own reference, how did you begin with the first equation you quoted?  I see that the term with the radical is the Y value at the intersection (from the equation of a circle), but how did you come to know about R^2/D being equal to the radical?

Comment: Never mind! Figured it out by just writing the equations... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that point $P$ is an external point from which a tangent $PQ$ is drawn at point $Q$ to the circle of center $O$ & radius $R$ then drop a perpendicular $QS$ of length $x$ to the line $PO$ (where $PO=D$).

Now, in similar right triangles $\triangle QSO$ & $\triangle PQO$
$$\frac{QS}{PQ}=\frac{OQ}{PO}$$
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{PO^2-OQ^2}}=\frac{R}{D}$$
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{D^2-R^2}}=\frac{R}{D}$$
$$x=\frac{R}{D}\sqrt{D^2-R^2}$$